# How is the virt-install --extra-args parameter implemented in source code

Tags: python, kvm

How does `virt-install` implement the `--extra-args` parameter?
I looked through the Python source code and found no information.

```
virt-install \
   --connect qemu+ssh://root@192.168.xx.xx:22/system \
   --name centos7 \
   --ram 1024 \
   --disk path=/data/kvm/centos7.qcow2,size=8 \ 
   --vcpus 1 \
   --os-type linux \
   --os-variant centos7 \
   --network bridge=virbr0 \
   --nographics --noautoconsole \
   --location 'nfs://192.168.xx.xx/usr/share/nginx/html/Centos7' \ 
   --extra-args 'console=ttyS0 --device=ens33 ip=192.168.xx.xx netmask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.xx.xx ks=http://192.168.xx.xx/ks.cfg'
```

Comment: is this the correct code? https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/56ca569dfc012e6a2b829ed6780c07f5d3f7ad27/virtinst/virtinstall.py#L968

Answer (score 1):

Source code is on GitHub and the command line argument is added to the [`argparse.ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) [here](https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/blob/56ca569dfc012e6a2b829ed6780c07f5d3f7ad27/virtinst/virtinstall.py?_pjax=%23repo-content-pjax-container#L968).

I used the following code to find out what happens to the hyphen in `--extra-args`:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> parser.add_argument("-x", "--extra-args")
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(extra_args=None)
```

as you can see, the `-` is replaced with a `_` so the argument is retrieved with `extra_args`.

Then I used GitHub to search the whole repository: https://github.com/virt-manager/virt-manager/search?q=extra_args
If you have the code locally, you can also use the "Search Everywhere" function of your favourite IDE.

Now I wish you good luck with analyzing what the parameter actually does in the source code!

Comment: How do 'ks' in' --extra-args'interact with' ip netmask gateway '?